# Convert Array of Dictionaries into Array of Values from NSFetchRequest

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nsfetchrequest

I have a dictionary that is being returned from a `NSFetchRequest` using the `fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType`  the dictionary returned is `[Any]` and looks like the folowing:

```
teams [{
    team = Canadiens;
}, {
    team = "Maple Leafs";
}, {
    team = Penguins;
}]
```

I would like just an array of the values, like this `[Canadiens, "Maple Leafs", Penguins"]`, how can I convert the array of dictionaries into an array only containing the values?

Full fetch

```
func teamNames(managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    //print("\(self) -> \(#function)")

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Players")

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 8
    fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = [#keyPath(Players.team)]
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch   = [#keyPath(Players.team)]
    fetchRequest.resultType          = .dictionaryResultType

    do {

        let fetchTeamNamesDictionary = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("fetchTeamNamesDictionary \(fetchTeamNamesDictionary)")


    } catch let error as NSError {

        print("GoFetch|teamNames: Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }


}
```

Alternate to accepted answer:

```
do {

    let fetchTeamNamesArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

    for array in fetchTeamNamesArray {

        let teamName = (array as AnyObject).value(forKey: "team") as! String

        teamNameArray.append(teamName)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you clearly know that the keys and values of the result are strings force-downcast the result to `[[String:String]]`

```
let teamArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [[String:String]]
```

Then map the dictionaries to its value for key `team`

```
let teamNames = teamArray.map { $0["team"]! }
```

Comment: I came up with another solution, but not as elegant as yours.  I knew I could do it with .map, but kept forgetting that I was downcasting an Array.

Comment: If you are going to use key or index subscription it's mandatory to cast `Any` to something more specific.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response.

Comment: I'm sorry, your alternative is pretty bad. Never use `valueForKey` to get a value from a dictionary. In Swift use always key subscription. And `valueForKey` - which belongs to `NSObject` – requires the ugly cast to `AnyObject`. That's very *objectivec-ish*